# How can I get a folder (in my project) from string? (C#)

Tags: c#

What I mean is, if I were to have something like this tree in my project:

```
MyProject > MyPrograms > Program1 > DoSomething.cs
                       > Program2 > DoSomething.cs
```

And I wanted to execute something like this in my main program.cs:

```
static void Main(string[] args) {
    DoStuff("Program1"); // Program1 being a folder
}

static void DoStuff(string program) {
    new MyProject.MyPrograms.program\* This being the string *\.DoSomething(); // This is the line
}
```

How would I access the program's DoSomething by using a string? (Asuming all the programs have the same file)

(PS: I do not mean Copy to Output Directory, I really mean at runtime in the application)

Example:

[image: example of project tree]

Comment: By MyProject do you actually mean MySolution. Why do you need something in the project directory anyway, one exe has no notion of the project directories of another project. If i am understanding what you want, these are just development concepts not runtime concepts

Comment: I want to be able to have a textbox with string, that goes into the method wich goes to that specific class in the folder. So when i type "Program1", it executes MyProject.MyPrograms.Program1.DoSomething.DoTheMethod();

Comment: Just because you have that folder and file structure it doesn't mean that your namespaces follow that structure.

Comment: Try `System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(...)` to see if that heps you.

Comment: Could you please explain what you mean by that?

Comment: @Flexan - The file structure doesn't dictate the class namespace structure, it's the default, but you can change it to anything you want.

Comment: @Flexan - Also, you're example doesn't make sense. A file must contain a class (or struct or interface, etc), but you're calling it like a method.

Comment: Make sure you understand the difference between the structure of the source code (project, folders, files) and the runtime environment (assemblies and types). The generated assemblies do nor know anything about the source code structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to choose what method or behavior you call at runtime based on a string, then try looking at interface and abstract class concepts. Based on their implementation, they can perform different functions.

```
interface ISomething
{
  void DoSomething();
}

class SomethingA : ISomething
{
    public void DoSomething() 
   {
     Console.WriteLine("A");
   }
}

class SomethingB : ISomething
{
    public void DoSomething() 
   {
     Console.WriteLine("B");
   }
}
```

In the execution, you can check for the string and create a type of the object accordingly of SomethingA or SomethingB and call the method.

```
 static void Main(string[] args) 
{
    ISomething obj;
    
    if(args[0] == "Program1") 
    {
     obj = new SomethingA();
    }
    else 
    {
     obj = new SomethingB();
    }        

    obj.DoSomething();        
}
```

If you want to create a folder in DoSomething method with a name based on the string, look at [How to create a folder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/file-system/how-to-create-a-file-or-folder)